# How to implement an enum with constructor in Swift like Java?

Tags: java, swift

For instance, we have the Java code like following;

```
enum Job {
    NINJA(3000000){
        public void attack() {
            //use Shuriken
        }
    },
    SAMURAI(4000000){
        public void attack() {
            //use Sword
        }
    };
    public final int salary;
    public abstract void attack();
    private Job(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

In Swift, I don't think we can define a constructor and have any methods of enum.

I found out we can have a similar structure in the following Swift code, but cannot have any methods.

```
class Job {
    class Store {
        let salary : Int
        init(int salary) {
            self.salary = salary
        }
    }
    class var NINJA: Store{
        return Store(3000000)
    }
    class var SAMURAI: Store{
        return Store(4000000)
    }
}
// Job.NINJA.salary
```

Of course, I know Swift enum can have their own properties.

But if you have more properties in the following case, we must have so many switch at each properties. I think it's not smart.

```
enum Job {
    var salary: Int{
        switch self{
        case NINJA:
            return 3000000
        case SAMURAI:
            return 4000000
        }
    }
    case NINJA
    case SAMURAI
}
```

So, if you were me, how do you write your Swift code in this case?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot add attack() method to Store class?

Comment: Not only to define the "attack" method,
I also want to define each property values close to their own enum element definition.

Comment: I've updated the code, so now it shows how you can override methods of custom members.

Comment: @MitsuakiIshimoto serious question: why is a `Samurai` paid more than a `Ninja` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can tweak your `Job` class in Swift so it behave as `enum` in Java:

```
class Job {
    class Store: Equatable {
        let salary: Int
        
        @private init(_ salary:Int) { // hope Swift will have private accessors one day
            self.salary = salary
        }
        
        func atack() ->() {}

    }
    
    class var NINJA: Store {
        class Ninja: Store {
            override func atack() ->() {
                println("Attack with shuriken.")
            }
        }
        return Ninja(3000000)
    }
    
    class var SAMURAY: Store {
        class Samuray: Store {
            override func atack() ->() {
                println("Attack with sword.")
            }
        }
        return Samuray(4000000)
    }
    
    class func CUSTOM(salary: Int) -> Store {
        return Store(salary)
    }
}

func == (lhs: Job.Store, rhs: Job.Store) -> Bool {
    return lhs.salary == rhs.salary
}
```

**Usage examples:**

```
var ninja = Job.NINJA
var samuray = Job.SAMURAY
var custom = Job.CUSTOM(23)

if (ninja == samuray) {
    println("Impossible")
} else {
    println("OK")
}

if (ninja == Job.NINJA) {
    println("Ninja salary: \(ninja.salary)")
} else {
    println("Impossible")
}

println("Object salary: \(Job.SAMURAY.salary)")
samuray.atack()
```

**Output in playground:**

> OK
>
> Ninja salary: 3000000
>
> Object salary: 4000000
>
> Attack with sword.

BTW: Should you need to compare salary values you can implement `Comparable` interface in `Store` class. Useful for sorting.

Comment: You need to override attack() method so there is no way to do it without subclassing. And there is no anonymous classes in Swift, so we cannot do in-place override like we can in Java.

Comment: Good! (except the class of NINJA = Job.Store)

Comment: This is lacking the most important thing; `exhaustive` feature. Without it, it does not even make any sense to create such workaround

Answer (score 4):

Example using **struct** in swift:

```
struct MyEnum {

    static let TYPE1 = MyEnum(id: 1, text: "type 1")
    static let TYPE2 = MyEnum(id: 2, text: "type 2")

    let id: Int
    let text : String

    init(id:Int, text:String) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
    }

    func getId()->Int {
        return id;
    }

    func getText() ->String {
        return text;
    }

    static func values()->Array<MyEnum> {
        return [TYPE1,TYPE2]
    }

}

func == (left: MyEnum, right: MyEnum) -> Bool {
    return left.id == right.id
}
```

Usage example:

```
for e in MyEnum.values() {
    println(String(e.getId()) + " " + e.getText())
}

let type1 = MyEnum.TYPE1
if (type1==MyEnum.TYPE1) {
    println("is Type 1")
} else {
    println("is not Type 1")
}
```

Console output

```
1 type 1
2 type 2
is Type 1
```