# Add field to enum in Swift

Tags: ios, enums, swift

I'm dealing with enum and subclassing in Swift.
Each child bring its own new properties which have to be stored in an Enum. This enum is declared with some values in the mother class. I'd like to add some value to this enum. I can't find out how to do it, I tried this without result :

```
extension MotherClass {
    enum Enumeration {
        case NewProperty
    }
}
```

Comment: Example using struct instead of enum:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802171/how-to-implement-an-enum-with-constructor-in-swift-like-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to add items to an `enum` is to add them directly to its declaration. You cannot add more items to an `enum` through inheritance or any other extension mechanism: the `enum` must be fully defined at the point of its declaration.

Comment: Ergg so how to make this modular ? I wanna write code so I can add other features later without rewrite the enums deep in code and so on...

Comment: @Aeradriel Then an `enum` is not a good choice for your situation. Enumeration should be used only in situations when you can enumerate all possible states upfront. If you need extensibility, use regular classes to emulate `enum`, in a way similar to how it has been done in Java prior to introduction of `enum` in Java-5. Look up "java type-safe enum" for hints of how it is done; essentially, a class was designated an `enum` (without actually being an enum), and fixed instances were added to the class to serve as `enum` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a protocol to solve your problem

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func code() -> Int
}
```

then create multiple enums according to your requirement

```
enum MyEnum:Int, MyProtocol {
    func code() -> Int {
        return self.rawValue
    }
    case ok1 = 0
    case other1
}
```

and another enum

```
enum MyEnum2:Int, MyProtocol {
    func code() -> Int {
        return self.rawValue
    }
    case ok2 = 10
    case other2
}
```

Then use MyProtocol where ever you want to get enum

```
struct MyStruct {
    var test1: MyProtocol
    var test2: MyProtocol
}

class MyClass {
    var abc = MyStruct(test1: MyEnum1.ok1, MyEnum2.ok2)
    
}
```