# how to extend an enum by another enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I want to extend an enum by another which add new values to the parent one.

I have a base enum

```
enum MyEnum: Int {

  case One = 1
  case Two

}
```

And I want another enum who should extend base values :

```
enum OtherEnum: MyEnum {

  case Three = 3
  case Four

}
```

Then compiler tells me :

```
error: raw type 'MyEnum' is not convertible from any literal
error: type 'OtherEnum' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'
```

Eventually I didn't make it work. I feel like entering a dead end.

Is it even possible ?
I know it could be done with a Class/subclass but in the end it would be IMO less clear
Thanks

EDIT:
I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242758/add-field-to-enum-in-swift) but according to the [last Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html), maybe it is now possible. I guess a expanding functionality is not adding new value...

> Enumerations in Swift are first-class types in their own right. They
>   adopt many features traditionally supported only by classes, such as
>   computed properties to provide additional information about the
>   enumeration’s current value, and instance methods to provide
>   functionality related to the values the enumeration represents.
>   Enumerations can also define initializers to provide an initial case
>   value; **can be extended to expand their functionality beyond their
>   original implementation**; and can conform to protocols to provide
>   standard functionality.

Comment: make sure you cite your sources when quoting - also, I don't think this question is a duplicate. This question isn't asking to add more functionality to an existing enum but rather, how to share functionality between enums without being able to subclass. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Of course we know we can subclass an enum. But you can adopt a protocol that has an initializer or method with more functionality inside of it.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: This question – as I understand it  from the given example – is how to add addional cases to an existing enum. That is the same question as the one that I chose as a duplicate, and the answer clearly states that it is not possible. – If OP meant something different then (s)he should edit the question to make that clear, otherwise I don't see a reason to reopen.

Comment: @MartinR fair enough, you'd know better than I

Comment: @MartinR : you're right, that's what I want to do, I just thought maybe it was possible now. It is a duplicate.